# how to count values of multiple columns with different categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to count values of multiple columns with different categories in a new one. I have 16 categories, but not all categories are in the columns that I need to count.
I have this df:

```
Tipo_Diagnosticos_Secundarios_2  ...   Tipo_Diagnosticos_Secundarios_3             
0 Enfermedades del sistema circulatorio... Clasificación suplementaria
1 Lesiones y envenenamientos  ...  Trastornos mentales
2 Neoplasias    ...                  Síntomas, signos y estados mal definidos
3 Neoplasias  ...                   Enfermedades del sistema circulatorio
4 Neoplasias  ...                   Enfermedades de la sangre
5 Neoplasias  ...                   Enfermedades del sistema circulatorio
```

I tried with this:

```
df['Freq_Tipos_Diag_Sec_2']=(df.groupby('Tipo_Diagnosticos_Secundarios_2').ngroup())
df['Freq_Tipos_Diag_Sec_3']=(df.groupby('Tipo_Diagnosticos_Secundarios_3').ngroup())




df['total_Tipos_Diag_Sec'] = df['Freq_Tipos_Diag_Sec_2'] + df['Freq_Tipos_Diag_Sec_3'] 


df['total_Tipos_Diag_Sec'] = df['Freq_Tipos_Diag_Sec_2'] + df['Freq_Tipos_Diag_Sec_3']
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If need unique catagories in integers instead string use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df2 = (df.filter(like='Tipo_Diagnosticos_Secundarios')
         .stack()
         .value_counts()
         .rename_axis('vals')
         .reset_index(name='counts'))

print (df2)
                                       vals  counts
0                                Neoplasias       4
1     Enfermedades del sistema circulatorio       3
2                 Enfermedades de la sangre       1
3               Clasificacion suplementaria       1
4                Lesiones y envenenamientos       1
5                       Trastornos mentales       1
6  Sintomas, signos y estados mal definidos       1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, at the end, I need to create a new column, in this new column, each number represents a category, and I need to sum the numbers of times of this categories appears in the columns and group by categories.

Comment: Thank you, but How can I add the column to my df?

Comment: @NenaRobles - Can you add expected output to question data?

Comment: The codes above works, but I need to add the new column(Tipos_Diag_Sec) to mi df, because when I print mi df,(df.info(memory_usage='deep'), I cant see this new column.  Ex:   
                Category  counts
0                  0.0          5559
1                 15.0         275
2                  2.0          256
3                  7.0         157...

Comment: @NenaRobles - I have no  your real data, so can you add expected new column from data in question? Because still not sure, what need, sorry :(

Comment: df['Tipos_diag_Sec']=df.filter(like='Tipo_Diagnosticos_Secundarios').stack().value_counts().rename_axis('Category').reset_index(name='counts') , but I am not able to create this column.

Comment: @NenaRobles - My main problem is not understand your output, because 2 columns. Is problem add expcted output from sample data counted manually?